# Can "Integration by parts" be used to integrate any function?

Tags: integration

I am having hard time understanding integration by substitution method so can I relay on integration by parts?

Comment: There is no _universal_ method for carrying out integration.  Here's a recent post for an integral where integration-by-parts is _useless!_ [ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371551/what-is-the-mistake-in-doing-integration-by-this-method ]  There are quite a few functions where one of the two methods is more convenient than the other,  others where only one is helpful, and still others where _neither_ will do the job. (And that's for functions where we _can_ write down the anti-derivative [_apropos_ of **avid19**'s answer below] .)

Comment: I doubt that integration by parts  could be used successfully on $2xe^{x^2}$, which by substitution is immediate.

Comment: You could apply it recursively, and possibly get a series expansion...

Answer (score 0):

If by "integrate" you mean "find an elementary anti derivative" then no. There are some functions that don't HAVE elementary anti derivatives such as $$\int e^{x^2} dx$$

You can't find an elementary anti derivative for $e^{x^2} $ (using ANY method) because there doesn't exist one.